# How to increase quality of photos taken with CameraManager

Tags: android, android-camera

The comparison is simple: I take a photo with my Custom camera which uses CameraManager. Then I take the same photo with the default Galaxy Note 5 camera. The largest size available for the CameraManager is `3264 by 1836` so I use that and set the Samsung camera to that same resolution as well. The results

- Note 5: I can see details in the photo
- CameraManager: I cannot see details. The image is of low quality.

Then I try setting the CameraManager photos with

```
 captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_QUALITY, (byte) 100);
```

Still no change. Well only one change: the file size of the photo taken with CameraManager becomes 2.3MB (it used to be 0.5MB) while the size of the Samsung photo (remains) 1.6MB. So even with the larger size, the photo taken with CameraManager is still of lower quality. Any ideas how I might fix this problem: How do I make the photo taken with CameraManager have the same quality as the one taken with the default Camera app that comes with the Note 5?

Comment: Also why is it that the Samsung camera can go up to `5312x2088` whereas the CameraManager reports a max of `3264 by 1836`?

Comment: are you using plain old `android.hardware.Camera` class?

Comment: Sorry for delay. I am using `android.hardware.camera2`

Comment: ah, of course, CameraManager is camera2. Sorry, i'm not familiar with this API

Comment: What kind of quality problems do you see?
Are the images you get in your app out of focus or at least not as sharp, are the colors different, is the dynamic range bad, do you see compression artifacts? Advice will heavily depend on exactly what kind of image quality problem you observe.

Answer (score 1):

> These are  some methods when we working on Camer manager,this method
>   may help you.

The Android Camera application encodes the photo in the  Intent
 delivered to onActivityResult() as a small Bitmap in the extras, under
 the key "data". The following code retrieves this image and displays
it in an ImageView.

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the quality is better in Samsung stock camera app because it uses the [Samsung Camera SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera). It's an extension of Camera2 API.

The SDK provides useful additional functionalities (e.g Phase-Autofocus). Try also enabling lens optical stabilization.